# PHP foreach stops after first iteration with no apparent reason

Tags: php, debugging, exception, foreach

I'm having lots of trouble with a foreach cycle in PHP.

It's not the usual "break\exit\return\whatever;" issue and I'll explain you the reason:

```
class Example {
     private function generic(/* args */) {
          global $db;
          $result = false;
          /* a series of if and functions, mysql transactions and 
             "throw new Exception" on rollback */
         $notif = new Notification();
         $notif->send(/* params */);
         /* if commit succeded > $result = true; */
         return $result;
    }

    public function start() {
         $list = array("abc" => array("foo" => "bar", "foo2" => "bar"), "def" => array("foo" => "bar", "foo2" => "bar"));
         foreach($list as $x => $y) {
             $this->generic($x, $y, ....);
         }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be with `$notif` declaration and\or `$notif->send()` function.

I tried to try\catch the entire `generic()` function and also the `send()` function but no Exception gets thrown up.

The `send()` function is nothing more than a series of queries and eventually (on user request) it sends an email notification via swiftmailer.

Another detail I can give you is that notification gets successfully sent and everything seems to work just fine on the first iteration, but then the foreach stops.

As I mentioned before: there are no "exit();" or "break;" or "return $x;" at some weird point in the function and so on...

Do you have any idea of what could the issue be, or how can I locate the issue?

Comment: In `foreach($list as $x => $y)` your variable `$y` is an `array`, is that the desired result? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Well, maybe the foreach doesn't stop, but just doesn't go through all the values. As Brett pointed out, you would need another foreach to iterate through `$y`

Comment: @BrettSantore yes it is an array and... it is the expected value

Comment: @1nflktd no I tested it doing `echo $x.print_r($y, true);`  inside the foreach and if I comment the $notif part, it just goes through all the values, otherwise it doesn't go after calling send()

Comment: What are the params in `$notif->send(/* params */);`, it seems like you have redacted a little too much here.

Comment: Try error checking, then there should be some issue which would be causing loop to break ..

Comment: @BrettSantore yeah (too much code :s) 

`public function send($type = 0, $user = array(), $data = array(), $timeout = 0)` all these params come from `generic()` arguments and they're totally fine as the notification is correctly sent.

Comment: So, can i assume `foreach($list as $x => $y)` is actually `foreach($list as $type => $user)`? because that's what you are sending to `generic()` right now.

Comment: @SyedQarib I am dumb. This is a crontab and I was taking a look at error_log, your comment made me -very spontaneously- say "wait, error checking... this is a crontab I should look at /var/mail/root!" and then... there's a class not found issue regarding swiftmailer (Y)

Comment: @XCore: glad you got to the root of the problem :)

Comment: @SyedQarib It's official: it works! Thank you very much!